# How does HTML Local Storage behave when used on a PC without any kind of server?

Tags: local-storage

I'm writing a simple javascript app that ideally can be run directly from a user's hard drive, and will need to store about 20kB locally. How will data stored persist, say, when the user moves the location of the files? (Html and javascript files etc). Will it count as a different origin, so make previous data unaccessible until the files are moved back? How can the script identify itself? Is there a best practice for this? Or do I need to have a local server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every file:// path is considered a different domain.  If they move the location of the html/js files, then they will end up with a new localstorage container.  You can't even access the same localstorage from two different files in the same place; e.g. "file1.html" and "file2.html" will access different localstorage instances, even if in the same directory and loading the same js file.

Comment: Excellent - exactly what I wanted to know. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

you could use a command line expression via a call to a helper script to find a absolute local file path on the app first running and then use that for storage, so when the file locations are moved it will not matter because you have established an absolute file path. You would also have to check for the OS first and then run the appropriate script

Comment: In the context of an HTML page (which the question is asking about), what is a "command line expression" and how do you use one via "a call to a helper script"? Then, having got such a path, how to you read and write to it with JavaScript?

Comment: depending on the system you could call a perl script and get that input stream for the javascript. I personally would run it on tomcat. I have had to something similar to this with a server that used saltstack and I had to run commands from there to access locally stored trust store

Comment: The question says "run directly from a user's hard drive" not "run from a locally installed HTTP server". If it was running from an HTTP server then it would have normal origin controls over localStorage.